# Display both forms together

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms Form1 and Form2, when program executes I want both forms to display but Form2 with `ShowDialog();` i.e user has to respond to Form2 before using Form1. How can I achieve this?

Form2 will take userinput and will display on Form1, so do I have to hide Form2 after user responds to Form2 or just kill it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `ShowDialog`, Form2 will automatically be hidden when hits OK or Cancel (assuming you've set the `DialogResult` property for any relevant buttons) but you will still need to dispose of it. You can do something like this:

```
using (Form f2 = new Form2())
{
    // Populate it with existing data
    DialogResult result = f2.ShowDialog();
    // Use the result and any data within f2
}
```

Comment: in Form2 I have only one button "login" so when user hits login he should see Form1. so still I have to use Dialogresult??
Thanks

Comment: @Ani: What if the user wants to cancel logging in? Usually you'd at least have the normal close button at the top right of the form.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in a form like this:

```
public FormMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Visible should be set within InitializeComponent (or Designer)
    Visible = false;

    //Can't be done in constructor, or this.Close()
    //would lead to an exception.
    this.Load += (sender, e) =>
    {
        bool loginSuccessfull = false;

        using (var loginScreen = new FormLogin())
        {
            if (DialogResult.OK == loginScreen.ShowDialog())
            {
                //Maybe some other public function from loginScreen
                //is needed to determine if the login was successfull
                //loginSuccessfull = loginScreen.CheckCredentials();
                loginSuccessfull = true;
            }
        }

        if (loginSuccessfull)
        {
            Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    };
}
```